# Are there some review papers of quantum combinatorical optimization problem and their application?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, resource-request, optimization, applications

I'd like to get recommendations for review paper summarized for combinatorical optimization algorithm and application. Are there any papers that have been organized recently?

Answer (score 2):

https://arxiv.org/abs/2112.07491

page 21:

[image]

Maybe https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.13936

> In this paper, we present a hybrid quantum-classical algorithm named
> the Classically-Boosted Quantum Optimization Algorithm (CBQOA) for
> solving a broad class of combinatorial optimization problems,
> including all unconstrained problems and many important constrained
> problems such as **Max Bisection, Maximum Independent Set, Minimum
> Vertex Cover, Portfolio Optimization, Traveling Salesperson** and so
> on. Our basic idea is quite straightforward: We run a classical
> algorithm to find an approximate solution (which is called the seed)
> and then use a quantum circuit to search its “neighborhood" for
> higher-quality solutions.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).